# Using a HTML and Javascript Function call into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Problem with using a HTML into PHP variable.
Please see the example below ??

```
$htmlvariable = "<a onclick="calledfunction('string',javascriptvariable);">Calling</a>";
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include those `"` in a PHP double-quoted string, you'll need to escape them:

```
$htmlvariable = "<a onclick=\"calledfunction('string',javascriptvariable);\">Calling</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes and escape single quotes inside the string with a `\` :

```
$htmlvariable = '<a onclick="calledfunction(\'string\',javascriptvariable);">Calling</a>';
```

Otherwise, this will produce this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING